# php не видит данные ajax, хотя по логам они проходят

Tags: php, ajax

Есть форма, с нее данные передаются через ajax на php. Вернувшийся ответ записывается в отдельный div. Стал разбираться что не так, упростил php по максимуму. В итоге отладчик показывает что данные приняты, но php их как будто не видит.

ajax:

```
$(function(){
      var reg_message = $('#reg_message');
      $('#submitReg').on('click', function(){
      var dat1 = {
            email: $('#InputEmail').val(),
            login: $('#InputLogin').val(),
            pass: $('#InputPassword').val(),
            repeatPassword: $('#RepeatPassword').val(),
            agree: $('#Check').val()
                }
      var dat = JSON.stringify(dat1);
        $.ajax({
          url: 'testreg1.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: dat,

          success: function(ans){
            document.getElementById("reg_message").innerHTML = ans;
            document.getElementById("test_message").innerHTML = dat;
          }

        });
      });
});
```

testreg1.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['dat'])) {
    echo "Goog";
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Скрипт всегда выводит Error. 
В консоли в пунктах "Данные форм" и "Полезная нагрузка" выводит полученный json dat.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто echo вывести не получится. Надо кодировать ответ в json. `$result = array('Good'=>'Good');echo json_encode($result);` И его обрабатывать `result = $.parseJSON(ans);` В некоторых браузерах в коде элемента выводится ошибка, при клике на которую видно что вернул php

Comment: @Pashok это не отвечает на вопрос, почему не срабатывает isset

Comment: Не срабатывает - значит такого ключа нет. И чтобы убедиться - надо вывести POST целиком. И даже в отладчике видно какой есть ключ в массиве POST.

Comment: А почему нельзя сразу написать?
`$.ajax({  url: 'testreg1.php',  type: 'POST',  data: {  email: $('#InputEmail').val(),  login: $('#InputLogin').val(), ... },  success: function(ans){ ... }  });`

Comment: У вас данные POST запроса - JSON, а не данные с формы. Принимайте этот JSON и работайте с ним, либо делайте [передачу данных формы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery) через data = new FormData(); data.append('email', $('#InputEmail').val())

Comment: @Pashok, но тем не менее просто через echo выводит данные из блока else.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, я и собираюсь работать с JSON. Но не проходит проверка isset. Не могу понять не передается переменная 'dat'  или не принимается на стороне php.

Comment: Тебе в отладчике даже показано что тебе отправляется на сервер. Выведи уже `print_r($_POST)` и посмотри, если отладчику не доверяешь.

Comment: @u_mulder, дело не в недоверии. Я пытаюсь что отправляется. Я отправляю переменную dat и в php хочу проверить ее существование. В отладчике показывает json данные. Значит ли это что он отправляет их  в виде json строки, не задействуя переменную dat?

Comment: Попробуйте json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')) и посмотрите что приходит там. Вы путаете название переменной в Javascript и тем, как вы считаете, она должна приходить в PHP. Это название будет приходить если вы будете использовать FormData, добавляя в неё значения под строковым ключом, и вот тот самый ключ и будет в POST массиве. Сейчас вы отсылаете обычную строку вместо FormData, поэтому используйте php://input

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, благодарю, буду разбираться. А как лучше, проще, корректнее(нужное подчеркнуть) будет поступить? Нужно из формы брать значения. Передавать в php. Он проверяет данные и либо добавляет пользователя в базу и возвращает положительный ответ, либо возвращает ошибку проверки данных.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поставить EventLeastener на событие `submit`,
используйте функцию `event.preventDefault();` (для отмены обновления страницы при отправке). В `testreg1.php` сделайте `var_dump($_POST)`, и посмотрите какие данные вам пришли.
Советую вам попробовать такую форму:

```
 $('form').on('submit', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();        
   $.ajax({
        url: 'testreg1.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(ans){
                 console.log(ans)
         },
         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
      }

         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том что вы проверяете в массиве POST ключ 'dat'. А у вас в js это переменная которая содержит объект с ключами email, login, pass  и т.д. Вот их и повторяйте в php: $_POST['email'] , $_POST['login'] .....